# Preserve Figure order

Tags: floats, numbering

Is there a way to ensure that Figure X is always before Figure (X+1)?
They are referenced in the text in the correct order but it seems that Latex rearranges their appearance within the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `H` option of the float package, this may happen. It could force a figure to appear while previous figures are not yet printed. In that case consider to replace H or use `\clearpage`, `\FloatBarrier` (of placeins) or similar before.

Otherwise please provide some more information, like used placement options and preamble or even better: a minimal working example.

Comment: \FloatBarrier does the trick for me