# How to make a chart be below a table?

Tags: floats

I have added a table and after the table a graph.

I am using \begin{table}[H]  (i tried with `!h` but it doesn't fix the problem) to control position of tables and similar code for `figures`. But although I put explicitly **the table before the graph**, the graph appears before. Is there any way to control it? Is there any way to order all floats in one shot?

What i have in my file looks like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Convergencia pm6}
\label{convergencia_cluster_pm6_table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\textbf{nºconf} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-SS} & \textbf{$\Delta G^0$-Packmol} \\ \hline
5 & -64.6 & -64.7 \\ \hline
10 & -65.5 & -64.1 \\ \hline
15 & -63.7 & -66.5 \\ \hline
20 & -64.3 & -65.0 \\ \hline
30 & -65.9 & -66.3 \\ \hline
40 & -67.2 & -65.6 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
and for images:

\begin{figure}
\caption{Convergencia pm6 cluster}
\label{Convergencia_cluser_pm6_figure}    
\includegraphics[page=1,trim=0 140 0 360, clip, width=\linewidth]{imagenes/all_results_thesis.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I think you have an answer at comments on your previous question... see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35125/how-to-use-the-placement-options-t-h-with-figures and try to use `ht!` or other options from the answer there

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7028/117534

Comment: `!` has to be before `ht`  (`!ht`)... sorry. It was wrong in the previous comment too... But the others are more experienced... So you may ignore my answers

Comment: If you don't want them to float, don't use a float. You don't have to put them in float environments, after all. If you really want it here, the answer isn't `H`. It is not to use `table` or `figure` at all. Use `caption` or `capt-of` if you need captions.

Comment: @koleygr No. That is the point of using those packages (one of). You have a caption. The caption gets added to the relevant list. It does not, however, float. The author of the float package has said just how much he regrets adding the `H` option. It is completely unnecessary always, and just causes problems in cases like this.

Comment: @cfr I show your edited comment (had not think about caption out of environment) and deleted the comment that was saying "In a thesis is suggested to have a list of figures and a list of tables and I think he need both floats". Your both above comments are really usefull for me (and I think for others too)

Comment: @cfr The way to solve the problem was adding this: `\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}`. That's why i didn't accept the answer, and i hadn't seen it also.

Comment: @koleygr thanks but the information in that post didn't solve the problem; I tried with [h],[!h],[H], any of them was helpful

Comment: @HernanMiraola `[!ht]` was my suggestion... but I thing @cfr's solution should work (Almost nothing could break it)

Comment: @koleygr cfr solution would be replacing \begin{table} by \captionof{table} or I misunderstood the answer?

Comment: @HernanMiraola just replace `table` or `figure` with `center` in your code and `caption` with `captionof{table}` or `\captionof{figure}` and leave text of caption as is. For example old `\caption{Mytable 1}` will become `\captionof{table}{Mytable 1}`... Add also `\usepackage{caption}` in your preamble

Comment: Your updated code doesn't show a figure-like object. What are you trying to show? For sure, if the tabular object and the graph object have to be placed together, use neither a `table` nor a `figure` environment.

Comment: @HernanMiraola Oh, I thought you didn't like the `es-noquoting` solution. That's why I offered another. (I know this is off-topic.) You don't need to accept my answer and probably shouldn't if you're using another solution.

Comment: @HernanMiraola If you'd leave a comment saying whether it worked or not, when you have time to test, I'd much appreciate it. (The site will be tidier if you accept, I guess, but I'm personally much more interested in knowing it works or not in a real Spanish document!)

Comment: @cfr Good. I will try it today. Thanks for the patience..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using `H`, which is unnecessary at the best of times, and counter-productive otherwise, use `caption` or `capt-of` and don't use floats.

In general, if you don't want something to float, the answer is not to make it a float. Trying to make it a non-floating float is just a recipe for headaches.

```
...
\usepackage{caption}
...
\begin{center}
  ...
  \captionof{<type of thing>}{<caption>}\label{<type:key>}
\end{center}
...
```

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\begin{center}
  some other kind of stuff
  \captionof{table}{My table.}\label{tab:mytab}
  \bigskip

  some stuff
  \captionof{figure}{My figure.}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: captions without floats]

If you have no other use for `caption`, use `capt-of` instead. (But who doesn't have a use for `caption`?)

Comment: It works good. Thanks cfr. Only one extra question: when I run latex it returns: `Package caption Warning: The option `hypcap=true' will be ignored for this
(caption) particular \caption on input line 17.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.`

Comment: I have seen that a solution would be to use \usepackage[hypcap=false]{caption} and I want to ask you if it is a good option to do that.

Comment: @HernanMiraola Sorry, but that's above my pay grade. There's apparently a `hypcap` packages, but it isn't usually necessary, according to `caption`'s manual. If you can't find something on this, I'd ask a new question so you get the hyper-linking folks. I mostly use it for Beamer stuff and then Beamer mostly takes care of everything for me.